# Tracking average number of results per query over time

Tags: math, logging, newrelic

This is perhaps more of a match question, but asking here due to the constraints of the logging apparatus.

An API accepts a batch of query terms, and returns N results per query. N is a non-negative integer.

For example:
Request 1 contains 100 query terms, the first 3 of which return 2 matches each.

```
[0] = 2 results,
[1] = 2,
[2] = 2,
[3] = 0,
...
[99] = 0
```

So the average results per query = (2 results x 3 queries) / 100 queries = **.06**, which I log.

The problem I can't figure out is how to accurately average in subsequent requests. For example a request 2 contains a single query with returns a single result, so 1/1 = 1 result per query.

My average results per query now looks like this: (.06 + 1) / 2 = .53, which I do not think is accurate. How can I weight the first request to obtain an accurate datapoint which can then be used in an equation to track average results per query over a time?

Answer (score 1):

You could weigh them by number of query terms? Then it would be (100 * .06 + 1 * 1) / (100 + 1) = .069.

Or simply (6 + 1) / (100 + 1) = .069. But it depends upon what you consider the 'correct' average of course.

```
r = nResults1 + nResults2 + ... 
= nQueryTerms1 * avgResultsPerQuery1 + nQueryTerms2 * avgResPerQuery2 + ...

q = nQueryTerms1 + nQueryTerms2 + ...

avg = r / q
```